# $m+ni+k\lambda,\,\Re(\lambda),\Im(\lambda)\notin \mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{C}$!

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> As said in the comments below, it's needed to suppose $\{1,\Re(\lambda),\Im(\lambda)\}$ linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, otherwise the result is false, according to Christian's example.

This is an exercise of the book [Funções de uma Variável Complexa, by Alcides Lins Neto](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es_de_uma_vari%C3%A1vel_complexa.html?id=NeW_nAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y) and, well, let's see it before I explain my doubt:

> Consider $\lambda\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $\Re(\lambda)$ and $\Im(\lambda)$ are NOT rational numbers. Prove that the set
>   $$\{m+ni+k\lambda; m,n,k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$$
>   is a dense subset of $\mathbb{C}$.

This is exercise 19 of the very first section of exercises in the book. At exercise 18 is given a suggestion (which, I suppose, may also be used at the 19th) that is:

> If $a\notin\mathbb{Q}$ then the set $\{m+na;m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$.

Let's see what I've tried.
Let $z_0$ be any complex number and $\varepsilon>0$ be any "radius". In order to show that that set is dense in $\mathbb{C}$ is sufficient to show that there is an element of it in the square
$$R_\varepsilon(z_0)=\left\{u+iv\in \mathbb{C};|u-\Re(z_0)|<\varepsilon,\,\,\, |v-\Im(z_0)|<\varepsilon\right\}.$$
It is sufficient because the collection of "open squares" is a basis for topology on $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$.
Now, using the suggestion, we have that there are $m_1,n_1,m_2,n_2\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that
$$\begin{array}{c}\Re(z_0)-\varepsilon<m_1+n_1\Re(\lambda)<\Re(z_0)+\varepsilon\\
\Im(z_0)-\varepsilon<m_2+n_2\Im(\lambda)<\Im(z_0)+\varepsilon\end{array}.$$
So we have that the number $u+iv$ given by
$$\begin{array}{rcl}u&=&m_1+n_1\Re(\lambda),\\
v&=&m_2+n_2\Im(\lambda),\end{array}$$
is in the square $R_\varepsilon(z_0)$ "near" $z_0$.
But now we have the following:
$$u+iv=m_1+m_2i+n_1\Re(\lambda)+n_2\Im(\lambda)i,$$
and this IS NOT NECESSARILY a point of the form $m+ni+k\lambda$, since $n_1$ mights be different from $n_2$. After this I've tried to think something about least common multiple, tried to find a pair to which $n_1=n_2$, or tried to fix $n_1=n_2$ and then to search for suitable $m_1$ and $m_2$: all of them without any success... How to garantee $n_1=n_2$?? Or maybe there is a completely different way of proving it...

Thank you guys!

Comment: I think you should look at the Archimedean property of the real numbers, that would help you show that for any complex z, you can find rational x and y so that x+iy is as close to z as you wish.  Good luck.

Comment: Indeed the claim is false, if, say $\lambda = \sqrt{2}(1+i)$. You would need $\sqrt{2}(n,n)\bmod 1$ to be dense in the unit square, which is clearly not the case. You really need $1,\textrm{Re}\lambda,\textrm{Im}{\lambda}$ to be linearly independent over the rationals.

Comment: @ChristianRemling, the unit square contains an element of the set of points of the form $m+ni+k\sqrt{2}(1+i),\,\,m,n,k\in \mathbb{Z}$, namely, the origin $0+0i+0\sqrt{2}(1+i)$. You say the claim is false, but I didn't understand very well your argument. For me, to show the claim is false, it's necessary to exhibit a square anywhere in the plane in which there is no elements of the form $m+ni+k\sqrt{2}(1+i),\,\,m,n,k\in \mathbb{Z}$. Could you be more precise?

Comment: @AndersonFelipeViveiros, in the example given by Christian the closure of the set $\{m + ni + k\lambda \: : \: m,n,k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ is contained in the set $\{a + bi \: : \: a - b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$, which looks like a bunch of parallel diagonal lines in the plane. I think this happens whenever $\text{Re}(\lambda)$ is a rational multiple of $\text{Im}(\lambda)$. Indeed you need the assumption that $1$, $\text{Re}(\lambda)$ and $\text{Im}(\lambda)$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn, thank you, now I understood what ChristianRemlig has said. But even if $\{1,\Re(\lambda),\Im(\lambda)\}$ is linearly independent, how do I show the result? Can you, please, help me? I couldn't do it... :(

Comment: This is pretty much (modulo the further assumptions in the comments) the standard result that $S = \{\theta, 2\theta, \dots\}$ is uniformly distributed mod $1$ for irrational $\theta$. It would usually be proved by (or at least introduced along with) ergodic theory, but it's not hard to show directly: prove that if $S$ avoids an open neighborhood of $0$, then a sufficiently close rational approximation of $\theta$ must actually be an equality.

Comment: @anomaly My difficulty is to work with TWO variables, in the plane...

Comment: I know, but you can use that result to get to the one in the exercise. Choose some $n$ such that $n\lambda = x + iy$ with $|y| < \epsilon$, then try to bound $x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

${\bf Summary:}$
We first prove that we can replace $\lambda$ with a multiple $(j-j_1)\lambda$ of $\lambda$ such that $\|(j-j_1)\lambda\|\le\varepsilon$ in the torus $T=\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}\times \Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Z}$, then we use that any line with irrational slope is dense in $T$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $z\in \Bbb{C}$. We have to proof that 
$$
\exists m,n,k\in \Bbb{Z},\quad \text{such that}\quad \|m+ni+k\lambda-z\|<\varepsilon.
$$
Define $d_1(-,-):\Bbb{C}^2\to [0,\sqrt{2}]$ to be the distance 
of the reduced values, i.e., 
if $z=a+bi$ and $w=c+di$, then 
$$
d_1^2(z,w)=(Fr(Re(z))-Fr(Re(w))^2+(Fr(Im(z))-Fr(Im(w)))^2,
$$
Where $Fr$ denotes the fractional part of a real number: $x-Fr(x)\in\Bbb{Z}$ and
$0\le Fr(x)<1$ for all $x\in \Bbb{R}$.

We can assume that $z=a+bi$ with $a,b\in[0,1)$. We will prove that there exist
$n,m,k,r\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $c,d\in\Bbb{R}$ such that
$$
d_1(k\lambda,r(c+di))=0\quad\text{and}\quad \|r(c+di)-(n+a-(m-b)i)\|<\varepsilon.
$$

Let $t_1\ge\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\varepsilon}$. Then for $t\ge t_1^2$
there exist $0\le j,j_1\le t$, $j_1\ne j$,  such that 
$d_1(j\lambda,j_1\lambda)<\varepsilon$. In fact, all values of 
$Fr(Re(j\lambda))+iFr(Im(j\lambda))$ land in $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and 
we can partition the square into $t_1^2$ little squares of side length
$1/t_1$. So necessarily two of the $t_1^2+1$ elements have to be in the 
same little square. The greatest distance between two points in a square is the length of its diagonal, in this case $\sqrt{2}/t_1\le \varepsilon$.

Eventually interchanging $j$ and $j_1$ we can assume that $Re(j\lambda)>Re(j_1\lambda)$.

Now consider $c=Fr(Re((j-j_1)\lambda))$ and define 
$$
d:=\begin{cases} Fr(Im((j-j_1)\lambda)),& \text{if 
$Im((j-j_1)\lambda)>0$,}\\ Fr(Im((j-j_1)\lambda))-1,& \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
 Then $d_1(r(c+di),r(j-j_1)\lambda)=0$ for all $r\in\Bbb{Z}$ and $\|c+di\|\le\varepsilon$.

Moreover, since $1,Re(\lambda),Im(\lambda)$ are l.i. over $\Bbb{Q}$, we have
$s:=\frac{d}{c}\notin \Bbb{Q}$.
Define $R:=b-sa$. Then there exist $n,m\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $|ns+m-R|<\varepsilon/2$.
But then 
$$
\| (n+a)(1+si)-(n+a-(m-b)i)\|=\|(ns+m+as-b)i\|=\|ns+m-R\|<\varepsilon/2.
$$
On the other hand, for each $u\in\Bbb{R}$ there exists $r\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that
$\|u(c+di)-r(d+ci)\|\le\varepsilon/2$, in particular, for $u=\frac{n+a}{c}(c+di)$ 
we find an $r$ such that
$$
\varepsilon/2\ge \|r(c+di)-u(c+di)\|=\|r(c+di)-(n+a)(1+si)\|,
$$
hence $\|r(c+di)-(n+a-(m-b)i)\|<\varepsilon.$
Since for $k=r(j-j_1)$ we have $d_1(k\lambda,r(c+di))=0$, this concludes the proof.